# What is the difference between red and pink leather gloves?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm being asked to enchant my gloves red or pink. What difference (if any) does it make?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Red makes your glove shoot out fireballs, whereas pink heals you.

Comment: NOTE: You have to re-equip after enchanting.